# error-page vs idle Monitor

Tags: exception, timeout, jsf-2.2, web.xml, idle-timer

First i would like to know if the session timeout in my web.xml is related to user inactivity or this timeout start when the user is logged?

I would also like to know what is the best practice when the session is timed out:

-using error-page for "ViewExpiredException"

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
    </exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Or

-using Idle Monitor with the same timeout value as my web.xml session timeout to redirect the user to the login page when the session expires.

Thanks for the answears
Best regards,

Comment: i ve maybe done some mistakes in my post but i think that i m registered here to learn lot of things about many technologies and wish i will have answears to help me understand :)

Comment: I made a test and conclude that the session timer in the wex.xml is related to user's inactivity.
I will choose ViewExpiredException to handle session problems by redirecting the user to the login page by adding the code above mentionned.
If i m wrong please telle me the right way to do it
thx